# Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function(t,g,u)

Tags: magento2, javascript, error, requirejs

I have a fresh installation of Magento but this error is showing on all of the pages.This may be duplicate of some other but I cannot find solution for my problem so asking here.
[image]

When I trace back it get me to minicart file and points here : 
[image]

Please let me know what I am missing or doing wrong I checked there is no jQuery conflicts and did deploy cache clean etc.
I have a child theme of luma. Actually I did replaced it's 2.3.4 database with 2.2.7 magento site. So codebase is 2.3.4 and db is 2.2.7 is this create problem?
tried disabling all modules and child theme but error is still there.
TIA

Comment: Are you sure that you have fresh Magento? any other theme installed or something? or any module installed? please brief...

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall it? I am not sure but maybe it's related to database. Which Magento 2 version you have? Have you added any module by composer for Magento?

Comment: Not any other , I have child theme of luma and there are RMA plugin from Land of Coder, magefan blog and amasty store locator installed

Comment: I also added some more info in question

Comment: @kunj Can you please help which type of database error it can be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I tried to add bootstrap js direct from admin content footer. I removed it now this error is gone